# Entity Framework Core - Database.Migration()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I would like to ask you if it is possible to proceed (in entity framework core):

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

using database user without ddladmin permissions?

What I would like to achieve:

> User without permission should not update migrations (without errors). However users with those kinds of permissions should be able to make migrations.

Currently, I am getting this kind of errors:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: xxx. Core
> Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: CREATE TABLE permission denied in
> database 'xxxx'.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to avoid the Migration if the user don't have the permission?

Comment: If user does not have ddladmin permission he gets "Create Table permission" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You give the user the `db_ddladmin` role
2. You add the `create table` grant to the user, like `GRANT CREATE TABLE TO Joe AS dbo`

I think the second one is what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that migrations entail more than just table creation.